# Python removing commas without using replace

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python output that is all permutations of words that are entered into a tKinter GUI. I need the commmas taken out of the output. I have used replace, but this ends up with a whitespace after every permutation.

```
def exactMatch(entries):
     words = [entry[1].get() for entry in entries]
     perms = [p for p in permutations((words))]
     x1 = str(perms)

     perms2 = x1.replace("," , '') 
     perms3 = perms2.replace("'" , '') #Takes out the Quotations
     perms4 = perms3.replace("(" , '[')
     perms5 = perms4.replace(')' , ']\n')
     perms6 = perms5.replace (" ", "")
     print(perms6)


"a b c hello"
 "a b hello c"
 "a c b hello"
 "a c hello b"
 "a hello b c"
 "a hello c b"
 "b a c hello"
 "b a hello c"
 "b c a hello"
 "b c hello a"
 "b hello a c"
```

As you can see above, every permutation output had a comma which I have replaced with a white space. My goal is to not use white spaces, and instead take the commas out so that all of the outputs line up with the first line of the output. How would I go about doing this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is `permutations` your function? Can you show us the definition? Why are you converting the permutations to a string before processing? Are you aware of the `join` command to join elements of a list together?

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the result.

```
for perm in perms:
  print(perm)
```

Comment: I dont fully understand this, where in my code would I put this so that it takes out whitespaces? From what I understand, thats just taking the permutations in my perms list and printing them, which I am already doing.

Answer (score 1):

One other way:

```
for perm in perms:
    print(*perm)
```

where `perms` is of type `<class 'itertools.permutations'>`